# AWS signature does not match

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using following API to fetch order details from amazon

```
https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2011-01-01?AWSAccessKeyId=aces key&Action=ListOrderItems&SellerId=seller id&AmazonOrderId=order id&Signature=ZQLpf8vEXAMPLE0iC265pf18n0%3D&SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&Timestamp=2014-10-04T18%3A12%3A21.687Z&Version=2011-01-01
```

But getting following error

```
<ErrorResponse>
     <Error>
           <Type>Sender</Type>
           <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
           <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
     </Error>
     <RequestID>ba13b457-bd7c-4413-b138-b216f887ac68</RequestID>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Here is python code to generate signature

```
import hmac

import urllib

from base64 import b64encode

from hashlib import sha256

secret_key = ''

to_sign = """"""

signature=b64encode(hmac.new(secret_key, to_sign, sha256).digest())
request = "%s&Signature=%s" %(to_sign,urllib.quote(signature))
```

Can you tell me what data i need to provide in  **to_sign**
and what is to_sign actually means?

Answer (score 1):

to_sign is what you wish to sign (or hash), In this case its the request. Sign the request with your secret key and then send the whole request with this signature so Amazon can work out if the request you are making matches the one you signed.

In you case it should be (except use proper dates etc):

```
to_sign = "GET https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2011-01-01?AWSAccessKeyId=aces key&Action=ListOrderItems&SellerId=seller id&AmazonOrderId=order id&SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&Timestamp=2014-10-04T18%3A12%3A21.687Z&Version=2011-01-01"
```

See the documentation here: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_ClientLibraries.html#DG_OwnClientLibrary__Signatures

Comment: Still same error.
I am not able to figure out where iam going wrong.